# Mirror swap FILES

Tags: partitioning, raid, swap

Mirroring (RAID 1) swap partitions is rather easy and recommended in some cases. It increase performence compared to single swap partition and increase resistance to drive failure.
On the other hand we have swap files, that are easier to manage and set up on the go, in case where you are running out of memory right here and now.

My question is: Can I set two swap files on diffrent drives to act like RAID 1 ?
These would be identical files, written and read simultaneously, providing same benefits as RAID 1 partitions where r/w load is balanced across drives. I mean it as an example where on each drive first partitions is "normal" file storage and only second is mirrored.
On the internet (and on this forum) there are multiple answers and tutorials regarding mirroring swap partitions and managing/proritizing swap files, but I couldn't find anything that would answer my question.
Setting both swap files with the same priority would stripe them (RAID 0), no ? Would that have better performence ?

Is swap files RAID1 doable ? Would it be better than swap partitions ?

Comment: Possibly related:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/what-are-the-advantages-of-swap-on-a-raid-1-mirror-device